# Server 2012 - OpenVPN 2.3 64-bit - very slow (10mbps only to clients)

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, openvpn, windows-10

I am aware that there are endless threads about OpenVPN being slow, but none of them helped. I copy-pasted countless arguments into the VPN configuration files on both ends and I am still clueless.

Setup is simple.
 **OpenVPN server**: `OpenVPN 2.3.12 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Oct  3 2016`

**Server OS**: Windows Server 2012R2 DataCenter
**Server CPU**: i5-3570K
**Server Connection**: 100mbps datacenter

**Client OS**: Windows 10 Pro
**Client CPU**: i7-4700HQ
**Client Connection**: 50/10mbps

- I tried using no cipher. It only gave a mere 300kbps speed boost.
- The CPU usage during AES, or BF-CBC is tiny, 1%, or maybe 2% at best.
- Ping seems fine. It's stable ~40ms or so.
- Both client and server supports AES-NI, but then again, no cipher is the same.

Though it can be a Windows Share thing.
But then I went ahead and tested the connection with **iperf**. With no firewall.
It's the same weak 10mbps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/szCmo.jpg

**Authentication** is via "secret key", so it's a one-on-one connection.
Both connection files are *vanilla*.
It's not even useful to post it here because it's the sample config with the only change of having secret auth.

As a last resort I can upgrade the server to Server 2016 if anyone thinks that would help, but I have my doubts.
Here is a screenshot from the client. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSOxe.jpg
Server has the exact same lines written to cmd.

**Ask away, post random black magic config files, I am willing to try all.**

**Update 1**: What I tried so far:

- UDP and TCP both
- Large, huge MTU, different mss mtu values
- Random crypto, all defaults, even 256-bit AES
- Compression on/off
- verb 4-5-6. Sadly 4 gives nothing, 5 is too verbose.

On TCP, with AES-256 and no compression, it sometimes jumps to 1500kbps download speeds on the client, but then it drops down very low again, so the average is still just 800kbps or so.

Comment: Just in case, both machines can "max out" their connection easily if I just download, upload something. So the network itself is OK. Ping is solid 30.